# When will the PayPal REST API be released for non-US countries?

Tags: paypal

I have seen on the [PayPal REST API's FAQ](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/support/faq#non-US-dev), that this API is available only for the USA.

I'm in Canada and am realy interested to use it.

Is there a launch date planned? Is there a way to use it anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not heard of a date yet as to when these addtional API's will be released yet to other countries.